# Bold headers in math mode

Tags: math-mode, bold

I am working in a scrreprt file and I would like to have two things:

1. in chapter, section and subsection headers to show the math symbol in a bold font like the normal text
2. to still then show those chapter, section, subsection names in the table of contents in the usual font.

e.g. in \chapter{Hello $1$} the 1 should be displayed in bold font like the Hello and that whole header should be displayed in usual font in the toc.

Hope it's clear what I would like to have!
Thanks and br!

Comment: Not that it helps, but is that really a good idea? What if there are both non-bold x and bold x in a formula, for example?

Comment: That doesn't happen in my case :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `\boldmath` to `disposition`.

Of course, if you want math in titles, you must also disable sans serif.

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreprt}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\boldmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example $x=1$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the default sans serif titles it would be

[image]

which is frankly unacceptable: inconsistent and largely awful.

Comment: Is there a command like `\sansmath` that could be hooked to the command in a similar way? (Disregarding any discussion about whether or not this is desirable.)

Comment: @Gaussler Not with Computer Modern fonts and coverage of math sans serif is not really good. Anyway, it would require quite extensive work for correctly defining a suitable math version.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work...the math symbols in the headers are still shown in normal and not in bold font...

Comment: @HelloEveryone You need to show a minimal example. Let me guess: do you have `\usepackage{mathptmx}`?

Comment: Yes your guess is correct - I do use the mathptmx package! Gladly I can give you a minimal example later!

Comment: @HelloEveryone With `mathptmx` there are NO bold math fonts available. Do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead.

Comment: Thank's ! There I get the warnings LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined and LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined....any idea why though?

Comment: @HelloEveryone With NewTX you don't want to load `amssymb`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works

Comment: Hm or not...now I got the problem that my self defined Laplace operator via \newcommand*\Laplace{\mathop{{}\bigtriangleup}\nolimits} is displayed really really small. Do you know how to fix it? Otherwise I'm gonna open a new question!

Comment: How come, @egreg, that you didn’t use the `\AddToHook{bfseries}{\boldmath}` solution instead?